# Change default terminal emulator on Debian

Tags: debian, terminal, terminal-emulator

I'm trying to change my terminal emulator from `xterm` to `eterm` on Debian Jessie.

I can't seem to find the tty config files. I've ran: `sudo find / -name tty*.conf` but that doesn't yield any results.

Where are the config files, and how do I change the default terminal emulator?

Comment: Seeing how xterm/eterm are graphical applications, I'd look if any of these are helpful: `ls /etc/alternatives/*term*`, `xdg-settings --list`, or whatever preferences menu your desktop environment provides. (Sorry, I'm not a Debian person, but this might help until somebody with Debian expertise steps in.)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by changing emulator? If you want a different one, just launch it. What default emulator are you referring to? Default where? In what context? How do you launch it? Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In Debian, that is `x-terminal-emulator`:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

Further reading:

- [Debian Alternatives System](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianAlternatives)
- [Virtual Package: x-terminal-emulator](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/x-terminal-emulator)
- [Debian Policy Manual:
  Chapter 11 - Customized programs](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-customized-programs.html)
- [Debian Policy Manual: 11.8.3 Packages providing a terminal emulator](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-customized-programs.html#s11.8.3)

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
There are 8 choices for the alternative x-terminal-emulator (providing /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator).

  Selection    Path                  Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/lxterm        30        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/koi8rxterm    20        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/lxterm        30        manual mode
* 3            /usr/bin/lxterminal    20        manual mode
  4            /usr/bin/mlterm        20        manual mode
  5            /usr/bin/txiterm       20        manual mode
  6            /usr/bin/uxterm        20        manual mode
  7            /usr/bin/xiterm+thai   20        manual mode
  8            /usr/bin/xterm         20        manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

The lxde installed as my gui ,so i select 3  /usr/bin/lxterminal.