# How to open vim not by uxterm in debian10?

Tags: debian

Call vim from menu:

[image]

In debian9 when vim opened:

[image]

In debian10 the vim will be opened by uxterm,it is more ugly than in debian9.

[image]

How to open vim not by uxterm in debian10?

```
apt list vim* | grep inst

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

vim-common/stable,stable,now 2:8.1.0875-5 all [installed]
vim-runtime/stable,stable,now 2:8.1.0875-5 all [installed,automatic]
vim-tiny/stable,stable,now 2:8.1.0875-5 amd64 [installed]
vim/stable,stable,now 2:8.1.0875-5 amd64 [installed]
```

Comment: Could you post the result of `apt list vim* | grep inst`

Comment: It will be in the settings of the launcher (nothing to do with `vim` settings, or Debian settings).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your Debian 10 has the default `x-terminal-emulator` set to `uxterm` while in your Debian 9 it is set to use GNOME Terminal.

You could run `update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator` as root. It will show a menu of installed GUI terminal applications, and allows you to pick one to be used as the system-wide default GUI terminal application.

Your desktop environment might also have a per-user "default terminal emulator". In KDE it's at "Settings" -> "System Settings" -> "Default Applications" -> "Terminal Emulator". I don't know about GNOME because I don't use it; feel free to edit this answer if you know.

Or you might install the `vim-gtk3` package to have a version of Vim with native GUI functionality built-in. It should automatically fall back to terminal mode if X11 is not available in your current session, but it's a larger binary with way more dependencies, so the default installation favors a simpler non-X11-aware version.

Answer (score 1):

You could install vim-gtk or vim-gtk3 that have true gui.

If you want to use your actual vim version in another terminal emulator, you have to [change the default terminal.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/257484/change-default-terminal-emulator-on-debian)

Greetings